# jQuery Galleria - Error: $("ul.gallery_demo").galleria is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, gallery

I have used multiple jQuery in my page. Two of them are working fine.When I tried to integrate the galleria script, it says,

Error: $("ul.gallery_demo").galleria is not a function

The code is working for me separately. Here's the code.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="css/galleria.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen">
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.galleria.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.gallery_demo_unstyled').addClass('gallery_demo'); 

        $('ul.gallery_demo').galleria({
            history   : true, 
            clickNext : true, 
            insert    : '#main_image', 
            onImage   : function(image,caption,thumb) { 


                image.css('display','none').fadeIn(1000);
                caption.css('display','none').fadeIn(1000);


                var _li = thumb.parents('li');


                _li.siblings().children('img.selected').fadeTo(500,0.3);


                thumb.fadeTo('fast',1).addClass('selected');


            },
            onThumb : function(thumb) { 

                var _li = thumb.parents('li');


                var _fadeTo = _li.is('.active') ? '1' : '0.3';


                thumb.css({display:'none',opacity:_fadeTo}).fadeIn(1500);


                thumb.hover(
                    function() { thumb.fadeTo('fast',1); },
                    function() { _li.not('.active').children('img').fadeTo('fast',0.3); } 
                )
            }
        });
    });

    </script>
    <style type="text/css">

    /* BEGIN DEMO STYLE */
    *{margin:0;padding:0; }
    h1,h2{font:bold 80% 'helvetica neue',sans-serif;letter-spacing:3px;text-transform:uppercase;}
    /*a{color:#348;text-decoration:none;outline:none;}
    a:hover{color:#67a;}*/
    a{color:#FFFFFF;text-decoration:none;outline:none;}
    a:hover{color:#CCCCCC;}
    .caption{color:#FFFFFF; font-weight:bold; width:700px; height:30px; float:left; padding-top:8px; clear:both; }
    .demo{margin-top:2em; }
    .gallery_demo{width:720px; float:left; padding-left:5px; }
    /*.gallery_demo li{width:100px;height:100px;border:3px double #111; float:left;}*/
    .gallery_demo li{width:100px;height:100px;border:3px double #eaeaea; float:left;}
    .gallery_demo li div{left:0px;}
    .gallery_demo li div .caption{font:italic 0.7em/1.4 georgia,serif; }

    #main_image{height:480px;width:700px; float:left;  }
    #main_image img{ border:5px solid #666666; width:700px; height:438px; }

    /*#nav{padding-top:15px;clear:both;font:80% 'helvetica neue',sans-serif;letter-spacing:3px;text-transform:uppercase;}*/
    #nav{padding-top:15px;clear:both;font:80% 'helvetica neue',sans-serif;letter-spacing:3px;text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFFFFF;}

    .info{text-align:left;width:500px;margin:0px auto;border-top:1px dotted #221;}
    .info p{margin-top:1.6em;}

    </style>

</head>

<body>
<br>

    <div style="float: left; padding-left: 40px; width: 720px;">
    <div>
    <p id="nav" align="center"><a href="#" onclick="$.galleria.prev(); return false;">« previous</a> | <a href="#" onclick="$.galleria.next(); return false;">next »</a></p>

    </div>
        <div class="demo">
                <div id="main_image" align="center"></div>


                <div style="width: 700px; float: left;">
                    <ul class="gallery_demo_unstyled gallery_demo galleria">                    
                        <li class="active"><img rel="images/image1.jpg" class="thumb selected" style="width: auto; height: 100px; margin-left: -17px; opacity: 1; display: inline;" src="images/image1.jpg" alt="SEAT COMFORTS" title="SEAT COMFORTS"></li>
                        <li class=""><img rel="images/image2.jpg" class="thumb" style="width: auto; height: 100px; margin-left: -17px; opacity: 0.3; display: inline;" src="images/image2.jpg" alt="BUS INNER VIEW" title="BUS INNER VIEW"></li>
                        <li class=""><img rel="gallery/image3.jpg" class="thumb" style="width: auto; height: 100px; margin-left: -17px; opacity: 0.3; display: inline;" src="images/image3.jpg" alt="Bus full View" title="Bus full View"></li>
                        <li class=""><img rel="images/image4.jpg" class="thumb" style="width: auto; height: 100px; margin-left: -17px; opacity: 0.3; display: inline;" src="images/image4.jpg" alt="BEGINNING" title="BEGINNING OF TIME"></li>
                        <li class=""><img rel="gallery/image5.jpg" class="thumb" style="width: auto; height: 100px; margin-left: -17px; opacity: 0.3; display: inline;" src="images/image5.jpg" alt="ECO" title="ECO AWARENESS"></li>

                    </ul>

                </div>

        </div>  
        <br><br>


    </div>
        <!--content_inner div ends here-->




                <!--- body -->




</body>
</html>
```

When I tried to integrate it in a page it is not working which also consists of the following code.

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/jquery-easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/jquery-easing-compatibility.1.2.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="gallery/jquery.kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="show.js"></script>

<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$(".jimgMenu ul").kwicks({max: 400, duration: 700, easing: "easeOutQuad"});
});
</script> 
<![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
$('.jimgMenu ul').kwicks({max: 475, duration: 600, easing: 'easeOutQuad'});
});
</script>
```

I have tried using noconflict() function and used jQuery instead of $ but no use.

Could anyone be able to solve this pls.

Regards,
Rekha

Comment: In your code, I don't see the JavaScript Includes to jQuery or any plugin(s).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you've commented out the `<script>` element that should be bring in jQuery, this:

```
<!--script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script-->
```

should be this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You need jQuery loaded before `jquery.galleria.js` or it won't work.

Your second example includes `jquery.js` but not `jquery.galleria.js` so try adding this to the second one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.galleria.js"></script>
```

You'll have to adjust the `src` path to point to your `jquery.galleria.js` of course.

Comment: I have included that in the header page itself.

Comment: @rekha: You've included an HTML comment, not a `<script>` tag. I've updated my answer to, hopefully, be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The path is the issue. Now it's gone but I have some other problem ie. Error: uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [@rel="images/bg.jpg"] what is the issue. Please refer my first code

Comment: I have solved the issue. Now it is working fine. The issue is in the version of jquery.js.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the plugin? I think you're missing that... It's not jQuery's core functionality.

this is it I think:

http://galleria.aino.se/

Comment: The code is working separately fine. If there is anything missing, then how it works for me separately.

Comment: I don't know what you mean under "works for me separately" but in this example there is no galleria plugin included.

Answer (score 0):

instead of `$('ul.gallery_demo').galleria`, try using `jQuery('ul.gallery_demo').galleria`.
If this works, it means that `$` variable has been overridden by someone else. Try finding that out or put your document.ready function a closure:

```
(function($){
  (document).ready(function(){
    // your code here
  });
})(jQuery)
```